# Can you Insert a Carriage Return within a listagg function that is also concatenating different elements?

Tags: oracle, plsql, concatenation, listagg

I am currently attempting to aggregate a list of concatenated values. However, I was wondering if it was possible to use a carriage return function within the listagg so that each concatenated value would be returned onto a new line. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thank you!

Here is a portion of my code: (Please note that this is also taking place inside a view join)

```
(select (listagg ((z.event_name || ' - ' || z.event_date), '; ') within group 
(order by z.event_name))

from 

     a_visit_event z

where

     z.subject_no = av.subject_no

and 

     z.visit_date = av.visit_date) event_name,
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `chr(13)`

i.e.

```
listagg ((z.event_name || ' - ' || z.event_date), '; '||chr(13))
```

Comment: FYI for others: I needed to use `chr(10)`. The use of `chr(13)` caused weird outputs. Oracle 19.3.